# convert json encoded string into array

Tags: objective-c

i make an API call, and receive a JSON string response, which looks like

```
{content = 
{key_1 = {"field_1" = "value_1"; "field_2" = "value_2"}, 
key_2 = {"field_1" = "value_3"; "field_2" = "value_4"}
}
```

I would like to transform it into an array (this is actually a list of companies), with whom i could use something similar to a "foreach" in PHP, to fetch the index and some particular fields.

Do you have an idea how to cast it to an array ?

(for example, in pho i would use $array = (array) $object; )

Thank you for your help !

Frederic

Comment: JSON does not have `=` or `;`, this is not JSON

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON object is very unclear. I'm assuming that key_1 and key_2 are the companies, and you're trying to make an array of dictionaries.

you would get your response JSON object and store it into an NSDictionary *response;

```
            NSDictionary *response = JSONObject;

            //Get the dictionary pertaining to "content"
            NSDictionary *content = response[@"content"];

            //Create the array you'll add companies to.
            NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];

            //Go through and add each element (key_1 & key_2) to the array
            for (NSDictionary *companyDict in content) {
                [array addObject:companyDict];
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The posted example is not JSON.

Notice that there is no "=" in JSON. The overall form does resemble a dictionary of dictionaries of dictionaries, not an array.

See [Introducing JSON](http://www.json.org) for details of JSON syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSJSONSerialization`.

`NSJSONSerialization` class can be used to convert JSON to Foundation objects and vice versa. You should use `-JSONObjectWithData:options:error:` of `NSJSONSerialization` class.

Example:

```
NSError *err;
NSDictionary *jsonDisctionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&err];
NSArray *fetchedArr = [jsonDisctionary objectForKey:@"content"];
```